# Is there a way in a custom QML type to preserve external bindings on properties?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I'm trying to implement a custom type in QML that will be used by other development teams. I want to assign a value to some properties of this type in certain situations, but I also want to make sure that this will not break bindings that the users of the type might have set.

I know that the [Binding](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtqml-binding.html) QML type can be used in this situation, but I cannot control how my type is used. Expecting to use Binding objects because implicit bindings will break does not seem too intuitive. Is there any other way to assign a value to a property without breaking an existing binding?

I'll try to demonstrate my problem with a more concrete example.

Let's say I want to create a custom text field based on the [TextField](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls-textfield.html) QML type. I also want to add functionality that if the user presses <kbd>Esc</kbd> during editing then the field's text is reset to the text it contained before editing.

```js
// MyTextField.qml

import QtQuick.Controls

TextField {
    id: root

    QtObject {
        id: internal
        property var textOnFocus
    }

    onActiveFocusChanged: if (activeFocus) internal.textOnFocus = text
    Keys.onPressed: if (event.key == Qt.Key_Escape) text = internal.textOnFocus
}
```

Then when this type is used, a binding is set on the text property. This is user code, I don't have control over this part.

```js
// SomePage.qml

import QtQuick.Controls

Page {
    MyTextField {
        text: someContextObject.someUpdatingProperty
    }
}
```

The problem here is that if <kbd>Esc</kbd> is pressed during editing then my value assignment on the text property will break the `someContextObject.someUpdatingProperty` binding by overwriting it. I don't know how to prevent this without saying that anyone who wants to use MyTextField have to use the Binding QML type for the text property.

Answer (score 1):

I think the way I would accomplish what you want is with an intermediate property that maintains the bound text but doesn't get overridden by your internal changes.

```
// MyTextField.qml

TextField {
    id: root

    // Intermediate text property to avoid breaking binding on `text`
    property string inputText

    // Display one or the other, but no binding gets broken
    text: useFocusText ? internal.textOnFocus : inputText

    QtObject {
        id: internal
        property string textOnFocus

        // Use this to determine which string to display
        property bool useFocusText: false
    }

    onActiveFocusChanged: if (activeFocus) internal.textOnFocus = text
    onInputTextChanged: useFocusText = false
    Keys.onPressed: if (event.key == Qt.Key_Escape) useFocusText = true
}
```

Then when you want to use that TextField, bind to the `inputText` instead of `text`.

```
// SomePage.qml

Page {
    MyTextField {
        inputText: someContextObject.someUpdatingProperty
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, don't use `var` for properties unless you have to. I changed your `textOnFocus` property to be a string.